# How can I import a HTML file into Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I'm trying to see how to import HTML into my Node.js file. The HTML file is named index.html and the JS is named script.js. I was trying to append "Hello World!" but it only says "Node.js Stuff"

Here is what I've tried:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.write("Hello World!");
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

and this is the HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>replit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class = "heading">Node.js Stuff</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you're running into, if any?

Comment: I was trying to add "Hello World!" but it only says "Node.js Stuff"

Comment: Maybe you can use express to do what you're trying to do here.
npm install express

Then use following as your script.js
//
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


//setting middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //Serves resources from public folder


var server = app.listen(8080);

Comment: @two Running this on my own I'm able to see "Hello World!" underneath; the one thing I had to change was to have the `readFile` callback also accept `err` (e.g. `fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data)`) because the first argument of the callback is the error, which will typically be null.

Comment: @Scott Now I've got:
```javascript
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.write("Hello World!");
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```
but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Install express:

```
npm i express
```

Node.js:

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname)
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile("index.html")
}
app.listen(3000,()=>{console.log("Started")})
```